# Multiple errors with Firebase auth (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch

For some reason, this function of mine doesn't work.

```
@IBAction func signIn(_ sender: Any) {

    if emailTextField.text !="" && passwordTextField.text !="" {

        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, completion: user, error) in

        if error != nil {

        } else {
            print("Sucessfully logged in");
        }

    }

    performSegue(withIdentifier: CONTACTS_SEGUE, sender: nil);
}
```

These are the errors I'm getting:
http://prntscr.com/f2iuye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this, you have wrong syntax with the completion handler

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: self.emailTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in
    if error == nil {
        print("Sucessfully logged in")
    }
}
```